# Requests giving "EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)"

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I wrote a program to simply just read the unofficial binary list from "https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/" and then use beautifulSoup to just produce a table of all packages in the webpage but I keep getting this error

`Requests giving EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)`

Here is my code also I am using a windows machine with Python 2.7.14:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/").read()
print(url)
```

I could not find any reference to (_ssl.c:661) after looking around, any and all suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Error continues



```raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.lfd.uci.edu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)'),))```

Comment: "SSL" error messages are rarely easy to understand. The number is a line number, inside source code `ssl.c` so by itself it does not help. The error may mean that both endpoints did not agree on common set of parameter to finish the TLS handshake. It may happen because both are not using the same protocol version, or because of certificates problem. You need to add more verbosity and logging. Do you have problems for the same URL but with other tools instead of your code?